# Angular 4: use loggedInMethod to change menu

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i'm struggling  to find a solution to this problem. I googled for hours but couldn't solve.

I need to change the menu item in my navbar template showing login vs logout when the user logs in and out.

I have 2 services, the **authService** which let the user login/logout and the **sessionService** which provides some basic functions to check if the session is set or not.

I want that every time i logIn or logout the user (so i update the localStorage in sessionService) my components which use this get updated too.

I tried with .subscribe, .map but cannot make this work. The only thing that make this work is call this.loggedIn.next(this._sessionService.isSetUserSession()); in login and logout methods.

Please, what am i doing wrong?

**navbar.component.html**

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownAccount">
 <ng-template *ngIf="(loggedIn$ | async); else elseDiv;">
   <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="logout()">LOGOUT</a>
 </ng-template>
 <ng-template #elseDiv>                       
   <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)"(click)="login(...);"> 
     LOGIN
   </a>
 </ng-template>
</div>
```

**navbar.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {AuthService} from '../services/auth.service';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app-nav-bar',
    templateUrl: 'navbar.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css'],
})

export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
    isNavbarCollapsed = true;  
    loggedIn$: any;

    constructor(
                private authService: AuthService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loggedIn$ = this.authService.isLoggedIn;
    }
}
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import {IUser} from '../entities/user';
import {SessionService} from './session.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

    private loggedIn: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

    get isLoggedIn() {
        return this.loggedIn.asObservable();
    }

    constructor(private _http: Http,
                private _sessionService: SessionService,
                private _router: Router) {
        this.loggedIn.next(this._sessionService.isSetUserSession());
    }

    login(user: IUser) {
        return this._http.get('assets/api/responseSuccess.json?email=' + user.email + '&password=' + user.password)
            .map((responseLogin => {
                const jsonResponse = responseLogin.json();
                if (jsonResponse.response === 'success') {
                    const userResponse: IUser = jsonResponse.user;
                    this._sessionService.setUserSession(userResponse);
              //this.loggedIn.next(this._sessionService.isSetUserSession()); ==> This makes this works but i don't want fo call this every time i change the session, i just want that the session syncs automatically 
                    return true;
                } else {
                   console.log("error loggin in");
                    return false;
                }
            }));
    }

    logout() {
        this._sessionService.clearUserSession();
        // this.loggedIn.next(this._sessionService.isSetUserSession()); =>> Same here        

        return this._router.navigate(['/']);
      }
}
```

**session.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {IUser} from '../entities/user';
import {isNullOrUndefined} from 'util';
import {Subject} from "rxjs/Subject";

@Injectable()
export class SessionService {

    isSetUserSession(): boolean {
        return !!localStorage.getItem('user');
    }

    clearUserSession() {
        localStorage.removeItem('user');
    }

    setUserSession(user: IUser) {
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
    }
}
```

Comment: see m answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make following changes.

> Use BehaviorSubject instead of Subject.

A BehaviorSubject holds one value. When it is subscribed it emits the value immediately. A Subject doesn't hold a value. When you set the subject variable, it doesn't reflect in the nav component.

**auth.service.ts**

```
private loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

get isLoggedIn() {

        return this.loggedIn.asObservable();
    }
```

Set the loggedIn variable in login and logout functions.

```
login(user: IUser) {
        return this._http.get('assets/api/responseSuccess.json?email=' + user.email + '&password=' + user.password)
            .map((responseLogin => {
                const jsonResponse = responseLogin.json();
                if (jsonResponse.response === 'success') {
                    const userResponse: IUser = jsonResponse.user;
                    this._sessionService.setUserSession(userResponse);
               this.loggedIn.next(this._sessionService.isSetUserSession()); 
                    return true;
                } else {
                   console.log("error loggin in");
                    return false;
                }
            }));
    }

 logout() {
        this._sessionService.clearUserSession();
        this.loggedIn.next(this._sessionService.isSetUserSession()); 
        return this._router.navigate(['/']);
      }
```

in navbar.component.ts
replace `loggedIn$: any;` by

```
isLoggedIn$: Observable<boolean>;
```

**An explanation as follows.**

The BehaviorSubject keeps the latest value cached which is set when user log ins or logs out. So when an Observer subscribes to the isLoggedIn(), the cached value is going to be emitted right away, depending on user is signed in or not.

This code will work for sure, as I am using in my current project.

Comment: As Aravind answer, this ones does not sync the loggedIn property based on the sessionService but set it true/false when needed. Using behavioursubject(false) at the beginning means that every user has to log in every time he visits the website, right? how did you manage the "remember me function" with local storage?

Comment: @SBO User's data is in localstorage. You are already checking this in auth service's constructor as well. When your component is initialized, Your auth service gets initialized and it set's the`loggedIn` . BTW i just checked your code in my solution. Just try `new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);` instead of `subject` and let me know if it works.

Comment: I think this will work. Is there a way to synch the localStorage.getItem('user') value instead of a boolean?

Comment: Just use `BehaviorSubject` and you can uncomment your code from login and logout method. it will work seamlessly. The code to check localstorage will be called only once - at the beginning of app. It won't be called again and again(unless you logout and login) like you've said in the question.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved without using `subject` instead use Shared service

Have the variable in service as below,

```
export class DataService {
   isLoggedIn: boolean = false;
}
```

In the component get and set it as below,

```
get data():string {
    return this.dataService.isLoggedIn;
}
set data(value: string) {
    this.dataService.isLoggedIn = value;
}
```

**Update 1** : Alternatively it can updated via another service also as below,

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(public dataService: DataService) { }
  update(value){
    console.log(value)

        this.dataService.isLoggedIn = value;
  }
}
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/lpBX2rc9MGZzvoWjZdYE?p=preview)**

Comment: This is a workaround but, i would have to call changing values for the service. I would like that my loggedIn data would be synchronized every time that the localStorage.getItem('user') changes

Comment: how wil you listen to the changes. without `subscribing` or calling `next` in your case

Comment: I tried subscribing but probably i did it wrong. Please what should i change?

Comment: @Aravind I read some articles, can you guide me which is the best approach to achieve this, `BehaviorSubject ` or a `SharedService`?

Comment: @AdritaSharma the best approach to achieve this is using `ngrx/store`